# Importing CSV to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I need to import my data into another Excel sheet instead of active worksheet.

I have 2 sheets the UI and the DATA_List. My button is in the UI. I want to import the csv file to data_list sheet.

```
Sub btnImport_Click()

Dim slect As String
Set r = Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    slect = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & slect, Destination:=r)
    .Name = "Data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to

```
Set r = Worksheets("data_list").Range("A1")
```

You will also need to change the line

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & slect, Destination:=r)
```

To

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data_list").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & slect, Destination:=r)
```

Comment: yow men thanks a lot but i have still a prob. the imported data is going straight at row 117 not in row 1. Any idea how to solve dis ?

Comment: and also the data is not counting per row, but it's importing by it's cell

Comment: I think (and I'm not sure, sorry) that if you just change it to the first cell (as edited), the data will just go in the right place.

Comment: no sir, I didnt change anything or add. It's just when i import my csv file. the data is just pasting by row.

what I mean is. the data is not importing as
Row 1
         2
         3.......
But it's importing as
Colm. 1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: sorry =( for the last time..
--scenario--
everytime i imported a csv file into data. the data is not posting as a row. my csv file has 25 row. So if I import a data it should be 25row and the 2nd one it should be 50 data in my excel. hope you get what i want to say.

Comment: Yes it works 'tl i changed the code into ur code. It works also but not like before.

Comment: I have noticed that a variable name has been changed to select - I have modified it as this generates an error. Plus I have given you new code, which I have tested and works.

Comment: Sir the code is working pretty well but the counting of data is my problem. I need to import it continuously until it will reach the bottom of the excel sheet.

Comment: You can only get the data in the file, not more than that.

Comment: @RobAnthony I think he means that he intends to import multiple files, and each file should be appended as additional rows. So the script probably needs .End(xlDown) to target the incoming rows to be appended.

Comment: @Blackhawk exactly thanks for understanding my english =)

Comment: @Blackhawk so do you know what is the right code for it?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd make it something like `Set r = Worksheets("data_list").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0)`.  In plain English the logic is "find cell A1, then go down the column to the last populated cell, then go down one more row"

Comment: @Blackhawk Yes sir exactly